# Styling a bootstrap thumbnail to make it look inactive and disabled

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap thumbnail in a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltjg5suo/) and I want to make it look more disabled/inactive. I can set the opacity to 0.5 and the cursor to not-allowed but I'm looking for other ways to make it look like its disabled. I'm new to CSS and don't know all the tips and tricks!

```css
.thumbnail {
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail" style="">

  <div>
    <img class="img-responsive" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: relative;" alt="space image" src="data:image/jpg;base64, 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">
    <i title="" class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x removeEvent" style="top: 8px; right: 15px; color: whitesmoke; display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 200;" data-original-title="" data-toggle="popover" data-event-id="260" data-content="Cancel event" data-placement="top"
      data-trigger="hover" data-container="body" data-space-id="29"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="caption" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
    <h4 style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">KevinsPLace</h4>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><span>7:00 AM</span><span> · </span><span>30 min</span></p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Style: Hatha</p>
    <p class="teacher-container" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Teacher: none</p>
    <p><span class="registered-container">Registered</span>: <span class="badge">0/0</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps just fade it out more?

Comment: "*I'm looking for other ways to make it look like its disabled*". Can you please define how to make it "*look like its disabled*" that would be additional to your existing behaviour? The question seems rather subjective. Like I could make a giant alert box on hover that says "This element is disabled!", but that's probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: Or, you can add another div and use it as an overlay